# What happened to my profile on this site?

Tags: bug

This might be fixed later on, but I just joined this site and my profile is all askew. I did not get the bonus when joining and my profile is all weird.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/289789/thegreatduck) is my MSE profile. I'm sure you can see the obvious issues.

(I know this isn't meta but I cannot post there so I gave this the gravity tag as this question seems like it might be something of high gravity, lol)

---

Extension by @peterh: for the case if this problem is already fixed, here is how this question looked in the time of the post:

[image]

Comment: @peterh thanks. I figured that since I technically should have the bonus it wouldn't be a big problem. :) If it helps anyone stack exchange gave me a page saying "we have an error" or something of that nature.

Comment: We need still 4 votes to the actual migration. Until that, I extend now your question with a screenshot (for the case if your profile would be fixed, I suspect there is an SE problem).

Comment: @peterh do you mean I should add a screenshot?

Comment: I did, you only have to accept the edit.

Comment: @peterh thanks for the fix, but I chose to leave my original portion unaltered.

Comment: Just an unrelated hint: The abbreviation MSE normally stands for [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/), so I got a bit confused at first. Mathematics Stack Exchange is commonly abbreviated Math.SE.

Comment: And speaking of MSE, this bug seems relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279526/why-is-my-profile-messed-up-on-a-single-site-and-how-can-i-revert-it

Comment: @chirlu that thread reminds of the time on a forum where you could see who voted a post up or down (cause it was a truly irrelevant fun feature) and people started joking there was a ghost on the forum cause deleted (aka perma-banned) users would appear as a space that took them to the homepage. I guess now I got stuck with access to the ghost account, eh? Well, I guess I'll just wait for this to be fixed.